# Changed home folder location in OSX and can't find gems

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I changed my home folder to another hard drive. After this, 'gem list' does not print gems I used to have before. I tried changing paths in .rvm environments and reloading my terminal but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: i would just reinstall them.

Comment: @maček: Sometimes the only option, or the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not used `--movable` for installing rubies then you need to reinstall all your rubies:

```
rm -rf $rvm_path/usr/
rvm reinstall all --force
```